# How to patch up ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on an app that requires a specific ruby version.
Ubuntu 12.04.3 and I did a sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
so it has installed ruby 1.9.3p0 and I need ruby 1.9.3p374

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The current best practice is to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) if you're deploying apps with Ruby. This actually goes for *any* programming language; perl, python, whatever. This is because the language version shipped with the OS will never be exactly what's needed, and it's important to be in control of exactly what versions are in use.

**So the answer is:** don't patch; instead switch to RVM or rbenv.